# essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable in r

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I used the data for random effect model with panel data
manager then I wrote this code with `plm` from package `plm`:

```
reffects <- plm(efs~sps+fe+st+maj+exp+hw,data = data.p , model = "random", 
  index = c("manager","time"))
```

and this warning:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In summary.lm(object, ...) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
2: In summary.lm(object, ...) :
  essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

I dont know how can I fix it? Is it related to the data?

Comment: Yes it's related to the data. What do you get when you look at a correlation matrix of the data?

Comment: Actually I am beginner in R and I didn't know to look at the correlation of the data . but I will try to do it now

Comment: Try `cor(data.p[c("efs", "sps", "fe", "st", "maj", "exp", "hw")])`

Comment: thank you it works. but how can I analyze it ?

Comment: acatually hw is correlated with all of them between 0.08 to 0.55 the rest correlations are not significant

Comment: also exp correlation with other are between 0.01 to 0.35 . should I omit them from regression or?

Comment: The warning suggests that there's a perfect relationship (i.e. r = 1) between some of those variables, maybe when you have it broken down by the managers and time variables.

Comment: so how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: By exploring your data more.